# Why is one linear-search giving me a different output than the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, search

I am converting pseudocode provided in the Algorithms Unlocked book.

The first pseudocode is the following:

```
Procedure LINEAR-SEARCH (A; n; x)
Inputs:
   A: an array.
   n: the number of elements in A to search through.
   x: the value being searched for.
Output: Either an index i for which A[i] = x, or the special value NOT-FOUND, which could be any invalid index into the array, such as 0 or any negative integer.
1. Set answer to NOT-FOUND.
2. For each index i, going from 1 to n, in order:
   A. If A[i] = x, then set answer to the value of i. 
3. Return the value of answer as the output.
```

Here is one version of solving this pseudocode in Javascript:

## Version 1: output: returns i as 5

```
function linearSearch(data, searchQuery) {
  var answer = 'not found';
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (data[i] === searchQuery) {
      answer = i;
    }
  }
  return answer;
}

var names = ["Jack", "Molly", "Tristan", "Jacob", "Jacob", "Jacob", "Steph"]
var result = linearSearch(names, "Jacob");
console.log(result);
```

and here is the other:

## Version 2: output: returns i as 3

```
var answer = 'not found';

function LinearSearch(A,n,searchQuery) {
  var answer = 'not found';
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i] === searchQuery) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return answer;
}

var names = ["Jack", "Molly", "Tristan", "Jacob", "Jacob", "Jacob", "Steph"];
var result = LinearSearch(names, names.length, "Jacob");
```

What am I doing in the code to achieve two different outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Your first function does not exit the loop as soon as it finds a match, but the second one does.

In the first one, when `i` is `3`, `4`, and `5`, the local `answer` variable will be set to `i`.  The last value is `5`, so that's what's returned.

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (data[i] === searchQuery) {
    answer = i; // update answer - LOOP CONTINUES
  }
}
```

In the second one, as soon as a match is found the function returns with that index:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i] === searchQuery) {
      return i; // return index immediately and stop iterating
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes much more sense.